# css class and clicked missing in dynamically created radio button group?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a dynamical generated form in which user select number of Kids and for selected number  fields are generated dynamically. Design uses `Bootstrap radio button group` for selecting gender.

I m able to generate forms and validations work with it as well but there are two issues with it:

1. On selecting a button `Success` css class do not apply automatically.
2. On clicking a button, it do not add `Clicked` attribute to it.

Below is markup of a correctly working form section where clicking them css and Clicked is applied:

```
    <div class="toggle-btn-grp joint-toggle">
  <label class="toggle-btn clicked">

    <input type="radio" name="ApplicantDetails.Gender" class="visuallyhidden" id="male2" value="m">
    Male
  </label>
  <label class="toggle-btn clicked success">

    <input type="radio" name="ApplicantDetails.Gender" class="visuallyhidden" id="female2" value="f">
    Female
  </label>
</div>
```

Here is my Jquery code which generate dynamic markup:

```
    function GetGenderMarkup(itrator)
{
    var ret = "<div id='Dependent" + itrator + "Gender' class='field rf-field'>"
               +"<label>Gender</label>"
               +"<div class='toggle-btn-grp joint-toggle'>"
                 +"<label class='toggle-btn'>"
                   +"<input required='' type='radio' value='m' id='male2' class='visuallyhidden'"
                          +"name='DependentDetails[" + itrator + "].Gender'>"
                       +"Male"
                 +"</label>"
                 +"<label class='toggle-btn'>"
                   +"<input type='radio' value='f' id='female2' class='visuallyhidden'" 
                          +"name='DependentDetails[" + itrator + "].Gender'>"
                     +"Female"
                 +"</label>"
               +"</div>"
             +"</div>";
    return ret;
}
```

and in last is my generated markup by above code:

```
<div class="toggle-btn-grp joint-toggle">
  <label class="toggle-btn">
    <input type="radio" name="DependentDetails[0].Gender" class="visuallyhidden" id="male2" value="m" required="">
    Male
  </label>
  <label class="toggle-btn">
    <input type="radio" name="DependentDetails[0].Gender" class="visuallyhidden" id="female2" value="f">
    Female
  </label>
</div>
```

Please help and guide what I m missing and how I can make it adding css and clicked event as in non generated forms.
Thanks

Comment: at http://api.jquery.com/on/: "If new HTML is being injected into the page, select the elements and attach event handlers after the new HTML is placed into the page. Or, use delegated events to attach an event handler, as described next."